# DataAdapter error

Tags: apache-flex

Dont know why the RPCDataServiceAdapter can pop up error. There is a part of the script related to the error.

```
        public function normalusercontactdatagrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllNormaluserResult.token = normaluserService.getAllNormaluser();
        }


        protected function addUSER(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var win:IFlexDisplayObject =PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, addUser, true) as IFlexDisplayObject;

            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);

            var e:FlexEvent;
            normalusercontactdatagrid_creationCompleteHandler(e);
        }
```

But the following dataadapter error is shown

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.data::RPCDataServiceAdapter/processDataMessage()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\RPCDataServiceAdapter.as:987]
    at RPCDataServiceRequest/invoke()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\RPCDataServiceAdapter.as:1786]
    at mx.data::DataStore/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::invoke()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataStore.as:3497]
    at Function/<anonymous>()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataStore.as:1716]
    at Function/<anonymous>()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataStore.as:1584]
    at mx.data::DataStore/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::fill()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataStore.as:1771]
    at mx.data::ConcreteDataService/internalFill()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ConcreteDataService.as:7504]
    at Function/<anonymous>()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ConcreteDataService.as:1306]
    at mx.data::ConcreteDataService/fill()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ConcreteDataService.as:1325]
    at mx.data::ConcreteDataService/executeQuery()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ConcreteDataService.as:1607]
    at mx.data::DataManager/executeQuery()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataManager.as:1493]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at mx.data::ManagedOperation/queryProxy()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ManagedOperation.as:519]
    at mx.rpc.remoting::Operation/send()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\remoting\Operation.as:212]
    at _Super_NormaluserService/getAllNormaluser()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\services\normaluserservice\_Super_NormaluserService.as:244]
    at normalUserDetailComp/normalusercontactdatagrid_creationCompleteHandler()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\normalUserDetailComp.mxml:80]
    at normalUserDetailComp/addUSER()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\normalUserDetailComp.mxml:93]
    at normalUserDetailComp/___normalUserDetailComp_LinkButton1_click()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\normalUserDetailComp.mxml:172]
```

the error on the line 80 and 93 and 172

are

```
line 80 getAllNormaluserResult.token = normaluserService.getAllNormaluser();
line 93 normalusercontactdatagrid_creationCompleteHandler(e);
line 172 <mx:LinkButton label="Add" click="addUSER(event);"/>
```

If I understand the error pile correctly, I think those lines trigger the errors form the dataService which is

```
at _Super_NormaluserService/getAllNormaluser()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\services\normaluserservice\_Super_NormaluserService.as:244]
```

How can this happen? and what should I do?

I discover that if I not call adduser.mxml in the pop up window, the error will not shown again. and the adduser.mxml is shown as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
         xmlns:userservice="services.userservice.*"
         xmlns:normaluserservice="services.normaluserservice.*"
         xmlns:specialcareuserservice="services.specialcareuserservice.*"
         width="522" height="732">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import services.*;

            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var userService:UserService = new UserService();
                var user2:User = new User();
                user2.idUser = parseInt(idUserTextInput.text);
                user2.userName = userNameTextInput.text;
                user2.password = passwordTextInput.text;

                createUserResult.token = userService.createUser(user2);
                userService.commit();

                var normaluserService:NormaluserService = new NormaluserService();
                var normaluser2:Normaluser = new Normaluser();
                normaluser2.user_idUser = parseInt(idUserTextInput.text);
                normaluser2.userFristName = userFristNameTextInput.text;
                normaluser2.userSecondName = userSecondNameTextInput.text;
                normaluser2.userAddress_Flat = userAddress_FlatTextInput.text;
                normaluser2.userAddress_Floor = userAddress_FloorTextInput.text;
                normaluser2.userAddress_Bulding = userAddress_BuldingTextInput.text;
                normaluser2.userAddress_Street = userAddress_StreetTextInput.text;
                normaluser2.userAddress_Dist = userAddress_DistTextInput.text;
                normaluser2.userAddress_Country = userAddress_CountryTextInput.text;

                createNormaluserResult.token = normaluserService.createNormaluser(normaluser2);
                normaluserService.commit();

                var specialcareuserService:SpecialcareuserService = new SpecialcareuserService();
                var specialcareuser2:Specialcareuser = new Specialcareuser();
                specialcareuser2.specialCareRequirement_idspecialCareRequirement = parseInt(specialCareRequirement_idspecialCareRequirementTextInput.text);
                specialcareuser2.user_idUser = parseInt(idUserTextInput.text);

                createSpecialcareuserResult.token = specialcareuserService.createSpecialcareuser(specialcareuser2);
                specialcareuserService.commit();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>



    <fx:Declarations>
        <valueObjects:User id="user"/>
        <userservice:UserService id="userService" 
                                 fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                 showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="createUserResult"/>
        <valueObjects:Normaluser id="normaluser"/>
        <normaluserservice:NormaluserService id="normaluserService"
                                             fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                             showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="createNormaluserResult"/>
        <valueObjects:Specialcareuser id="specialcareuser"/>
        <specialcareuserservice:SpecialcareuserService id="specialcareuserService"
                                                       fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                                       showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="createSpecialcareuserResult"/>


    </fx:Declarations>




    <s:Form x="43" y="10" width="445" height="727" >
        <s:FormItem label="IdUser">
            <s:TextInput id="idUserTextInput" text="{user.idUser}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="UserName">
            <s:TextInput id="userNameTextInput" text="{user.userName}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Password">
            <s:TextInput id="passwordTextInput" text="{user.password}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormHeading width="266" label="User Detail (Name, address...)"/>
        <s:FormItem label="Frist Name">
            <s:TextInput id="userFristNameTextInput" text="{normaluser.userFristName}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Second Name">
            <s:TextInput id="userSecondNameTextInput" text="{normaluser.userSecondName}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Flat">
            <s:TextInput id="userAddress_FlatTextInput" text="{normaluser.userAddress_Flat}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Floor">
            <s:TextInput id="userAddress_FloorTextInput" text="{normaluser.userAddress_Floor}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="UserAddress_Bulding">
            <s:TextInput id="userAddress_BuldingTextInput" text="{normaluser.userAddress_Bulding}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Street">
            <s:TextInput id="userAddress_StreetTextInput" text="{normaluser.userAddress_Street}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Dist">
            <s:TextInput id="userAddress_DistTextInput" text="{normaluser.userAddress_Dist}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Country">
            <s:TextInput id="userAddress_CountryTextInput" text="{normaluser.userAddress_Country}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormHeading label="Special Requirement"/>

        <s:FormItem label="Care Requirement">
            <s:helpContent>
                <s:VGroup>
                    <s:Label text="Special Requirement?"></s:Label>
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:helpContent>
            <s:TextInput id="specialCareRequirement_idspecialCareRequirementTextInput"
                         text="{specialcareuser.specialCareRequirement_idspecialCareRequirement}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
            <s:Button id="button" label="CreateUser" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:Form>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: What's on the other end of the RPC request? And this only happens sometimes - not every time?

Comment: This only happen when I call the adduser.mxml form the addUSER function. and on the other end of the RPC request is a php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason your RPC connection isn't available when CreationComplete() is called. You can either delay calling it (a short timer?) or call some other function from CreationComplete that delays until the RPC connection is setup. Perhaps display a 'working...' dialog in the meanwhile.

Either way you should test for null at that point and trap the error.

Comment: I guess Flex don't queueing the Dataservices call very well, so many dataservices error pop up while I call a single dataservice multi-times =.='. I will try to quenening the dataservices call. Hope it work. Thanks.